# Can I change Gmail attachment download location on android phone?

Tags: applications, gmail

Basically on my Huawei Mate 20 I am using Gmail. When I get an e-mail with an attachment and download it, it always goes to the "Downloads" folder. But I want to be able to choose the location each time I download an attachment. Is it possible?

Comment: Not the gmail app is only mail client. I use "open mail", there you can choose, where do you want to download the attachment, although it is an app-wide setting and still you can not choose every time.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Gmail app doesn't have this feature of choosing download location.
 Instead of using the Gmail app, open the website on google chrome. In Google Chrome's settings, go to Advanced Settings section and click on Downloads. There, you can choose to ask the download location for each file or change the download location for all files.

Comment: I have this already setup in chrome on my phone but Gmail does not ask me anyway